# Dynamically created table - Vanilla Javascript only - not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I have a function that goes through and sorts items and their quantity and is supposed to display them in a table.

Nothing is appearing in the DOM or browser. Am I calling the function wrong or something?

I have an **index.html** file linked to my **index.js** file using a script.

There are no errors showing in chrome dev tools.

**INSTRUCTION**

Display the shelf and item pairings by calling the following

`function displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);`

```js
function main() {

  let yesterdaysOrders = [

      {
        id: 1,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 01",
            quantity: 1
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 02",
            quantity: 3
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 03",
            quantity: 25
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 04",
            quantity: 12
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 01",
            quantity: 1
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 08",
            quantity: 42
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 09",
            quantity: 13
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 12",
            quantity: 37
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        orderLines: [{
          itemName: "Item 12",
          quantity: 16
        }, ],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 10",
            quantity: 11
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 11",
            quantity: 10
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 06",
            quantity: 7
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 2
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 12",
            quantity: 14
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        orderLines: [{
          itemName: "Item 05",
          quantity: 17
        }, ],
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 03",
            quantity: 5
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 2
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 02",
            quantity: 13
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 7
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 09",
            quantity: 2
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 01",
            quantity: 4
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 06",
            quantity: 17
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 3
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 11",
            quantity: 12
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 12",
            quantity: 1
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
    result = Array.from(
      yesterdaysOrders.reduce((acc, {
        orderLines
      }) => {
        orderLines.forEach(({
          itemName,
          quantity
        }) => acc.set(itemName, (acc.get(itemName) || 0) + quantity));
        return acc;
      }, new Map), ([itemName, quantity]) => ({
        itemName,
        quantity
      }));



  result.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.quantity > b.quantity) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.quantity < b.quantity) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }

  });

  function displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName) {

    let table = document.createElement('table');

    document.body.appendChild(table); 

    for (let r in row) {

      let tr = document.createElement('tr'); 

      table.appendChild(tr); // Append to <table> node

      for (let c in cell) {

        let tdElement = document.createElement('td');

        tdElement.innerHTML = result[i][j];

        tr.appendChild(tdElement);

      }


    }

  console.log(displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName));

  }
  
}

main();
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

`ShelfName | itemName (w/quantity)
    1         Item 12: 68

    2            ''
    ''           ''
    ''           ''`

Comment: The code is getting an error: `shelfName is not defined`.

Comment: `console.log(displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName));` should be inside the `displayShelfItemPair()` function.

Comment: you're right, i moved the `displayShelfItemPair` function. now no errors, but nothing showing up

Comment: You need to move the console.log statement, not the function.

Comment: should be running now

Comment: `result` is not a 2-dimensional array, it's an array of objects. What do you expect `result[i][j]` to show?

Comment: @Barmar according to the OP, "There are no errors showing in chrome dev tools.". Then the OP's logic for generating the array should be alright.

Comment: I'm just not sure why nothing is showing up at all and no errors to my knowledge.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes, i was looking for a rendered function that would work with what i had. I tried my own implementation with similar syntax but same results. no errors but nothing showing

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu appreciate it. `Display the shelf and item pairings by calling the following function:displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName);` is what the directions were calling for

Comment: Yep, but you weren't iterating over the reduced results calling that function for each item. Also, your function created a table upon each iteration (you don't want that, you want to create the table before you start iterating) and it used `row` and `cell` vars, which you never defined. So i presumed you took it from some place else.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu got it, appreciate that, can you take a look at my desired output, i need to use those parameters in the instructions and need a table to display the results as above.

Comment: Refresh it one more time. I simplified it a bit (there's no point in naming the function if you're calling it right away). You can simply run it: `(function(){/* code */}())`. Naming is useful when you want to store it and call at a later time.

Comment: It's not clear where `Shelf Name` is coming from. Is it simply an index?

Comment: @AnisR. `result[i][j]` wouldn't report an error, it would just return `undefined` every time.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu take a look at the instructions here https://imgur.com/pJLkVni

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i guess i don't need the quantity then, just the itemName

Comment: If I knew it was a homework, wouldn't have tried to help. The whole point of an exercise/homework is the knowledge you get from solving it. If someone else does it for you, you don't learn.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu it's not homework, these are extra exercises that want you to use vanilla JS to create a table dynamically.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Plus I was just asking why my code wasn't working and some pointers, i appreciate your solution as it cleared up some of what I was doing wrong, that helps me more than you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were iterating through objects that did not exist. For instance, `for (let r in row)` there is no `row`. I rewrote the function to hopefully get you closer.

```js
function main() {

  let yesterdaysOrders = [

      {
        id: 1,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 01",
            quantity: 1
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 02",
            quantity: 3
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 03",
            quantity: 25
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 04",
            quantity: 12
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 01",
            quantity: 1
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 08",
            quantity: 42
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 09",
            quantity: 13
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 12",
            quantity: 37
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        orderLines: [{
          itemName: "Item 12",
          quantity: 16
        }, ],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 10",
            quantity: 11
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 11",
            quantity: 10
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 06",
            quantity: 7
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 2
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 12",
            quantity: 14
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        orderLines: [{
          itemName: "Item 05",
          quantity: 17
        }, ],
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 03",
            quantity: 5
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 2
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 02",
            quantity: 13
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 7
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 09",
            quantity: 2
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 01",
            quantity: 4
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 06",
            quantity: 17
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 07",
            quantity: 3
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        orderLines: [{
            itemName: "Item 11",
            quantity: 12
          },
          {
            itemName: "Item 12",
            quantity: 1
          },
        ],
      }
    ],
    result = Array.from(
      yesterdaysOrders.reduce((acc, {
        orderLines
      }) => {
        orderLines.forEach(({
          itemName,
          quantity
        }) => acc.set(itemName, (acc.get(itemName) || 0) + quantity));
        return acc;
      }, new Map), ([itemName, quantity]) => ({
        itemName,
        quantity
      }));



  result.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.quantity > b.quantity) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.quantity < b.quantity) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }

  });

  function displayShelfItemPairs() {

    let table = document.createElement('table');

    document.body.appendChild(table); 
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>ShelfName</th><th>itemName (w/quantity)</th></tr>"

    let shelf = 1;
    for (let r of result) {

      let tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
      table.appendChild(tr); // Append to <table> node
      tr.innerHTML = "<td>" + shelf + "</td><td>" + r.itemName + ": " + r.quantity + "</td>";
      shelf++

    }
  }
  displayShelfItemPairs()
  
}

main();
```

Comment: You had a few other logical errors. For instance, there is a big difference between `for (let r in row)` vs `for (let r of row)`. You should look that up. Also, you didn't actually call the code to build the table. Your line `console.log(displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName));` is already inside the function that you are trying to call, and shelfName and itemName are not defined. Notice how I moved that out.

Comment: and yes you're right about the `for in and for of`, i need to look more closely

Comment: While you're learning javascript, learn to use the debugger in your browser. You can put breakpoints and stop the program in mid-action to inspect variables and your assumptions. That's how you find things like, my function isn't even called, or that variable isn't defined or doesn't have what I expected. Please accept this answer if it helped you so folks don't keep supplying answers months from now ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As I now figured out, output will be the same regardless whether you append children before or after filling them.

<s>In your function `displayShelfItemPair`, you are appending the new table element before filling it, which is why is displays nothing on the page.</s>

Fill the table element with rows, etc., and then append it to the document:

```
function displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName) {

    let table = document.createElement('table');


    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      let tr = document.createElement('tr'); 


      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        let tdElement = document.createElement('td');
        tdElement.innerHTML = result[i][j];
        tr.appendChild(tdElement);

      }
      table.appendChild(tr); // Append to <table> node AFTER it is filled


    }
    document.body.appendChild(table); //append table to body AFTER it is filled
    console.log(displayShelfItemPair(shelfName, itemName));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but even when I use your example, nothing is showing up. No errors either.

Comment: @and1 Your original code seems fine as it is. Have you tried emptying the browser cache and hard reloading the page? In Chrome, simply open dev tools (F12), right click on the refresh icon and select "Empty cache and hard reload".